# writeForeignSPSS "Cannot handle character variables longer than 255"

Tags: r

I have a dataset that I'm supposed to export to SPSS but I get an error and I don't really know where it comes from. Is the limitation on the side of R or does the function stop because SPSS won't be able to handle the variable? (I'm not familiar with SPSS at all).

```
Error in writeForeignSPSS(df = list(var1 = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,  : 
  Cannot handle character variables longer than 255
```

What could be a possible workaround?
Is there a way to see the source code for writeForeignSPSS (which is called for by write.Foreign(...,package=c("SPSS"))?

This is what I tried, because I think it would be helpful if I could see the code.

```
> write.foreign
function (df, datafile, codefile, package = c("SPSS", "Stata", 
    "SAS"), ...) 
{
    do.call(paste("writeForeign", package, sep = ""), c(list(df = df, 
        datafile = datafile, codefile = codefile), ...))
    invisible(NULL)
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000a2f8190>
<environment: namespace:foreign>
> writeForeignSPSS
Error: object 'writeForeignSPSS' not found
```

Comment: That's an SPSS format limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

library(foreign)

write.foreign(mydata, "c:/data.txt", "c:/data.sps",   package="SPSS")

SPSS max strings' length is 32767 chars, previously it was limited to 255 chars

Comment: Sorry for the late respone. That's what I've tried and where I get the error from.